# Model won't follow its armature in pose mode

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I've set up a rig and built it around my model, and I've linked it to my model but when I rotate the bones in pose mode, the character doesn't move with them.

My rig is the human meta rig that comes with rigify. I've seen tons of videos of it working. Why isn't it working on mine?

My character was made by creating different body parts and joining them together into the same object, then a texture was added by unwrapping them in texture mode.

Comment: Could you describe what steps you have taken. Did you parent the rig to your model, pressed the generate button. It would probably best when you add the .blend

Comment: Sounds like you haven't weight painted.

Answer (score 11):

try following these steps

after *joining* all the separate parts and the body mesh together, you should *parent* the body mesh to the armature by ( in object mode )

1. selecting the mesh then the armature and pressing **Ctrl P**
2. select *Armature Deform* >> *With Automatic Weights*
3. select only the mesh and go to *Modifiers*
4. deselect *Bone Envelopes* in the *Armature Modifier*

[image]

5. press **Tab** to enter *Edit Mode* and navigate to *Vertex Groups*
6. ensure only necessary vertices belong to each *Vertex Group*

[image]

7. press **Tab** to enter *Object Mode*
8. select the armature and press **Ctrl Tab** to enter *Pose Mode*
9. select a bone and move by pressing **G** or rotate by pressing **R**

hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and the apparent solution is wasn't obvious to me.  You see, I had done the weight painting setup against the base human meta-rig.  However, it is only used for getting the base setup of the rigify armature.  When you reparent the model to the generated rigify armature, it doesn't work because it is not using the same bones as the human meta-rig.  What you must do is parent against the rigify armature with Automatic Weights (or empty groups), and then do the weight painting process.

Comment: Haha. I've made the same mistake some time ago and was really angry (because spent a lot of time weight painting the model). Wish I had found your answer earlier... :).