# Rigging is not working

Tags: armature, rigging

My problem is that when I try to link the armature with the mesh and go into to pose mode, the  mesh doesn´t follow the armature. I followed the steps **[here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5151/model-wont-follow-its-armature-in-pose-mode)** but it didn't work.

Previously, in another project, I worked with a mesh of a man. I followed the same steps to skinning and it worked.

I don't know if the mesh in this new project is right. It's a very simple project. The mesh is a cylinder

[image]

Comment: Also see, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/782/how-can-i-automatically-generate-vertex-groups-for-an-armature

Answer (score 3):

Due to the lack of information provided I cannot be entirely sure what the problem is. My guess is that you do not have enough resolution in the cylinder for it to deform.

1. Select the cylinder and go into edit mode
2. Add some edgeloop along the height of the cylinder, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> -> mouse wheel up to increase the number of loops

   [image]
3. Go into object mode and select the cylinder and the armature, in that order.
4. Parent the mesh to the armature, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> -> With Automatic Weights

   [image]
5. Now you can go into pose mode and pose the bones as you desire.

   [image]